# Iterating through a string in C

Tags: c, string, loops, file-io

In my code, I'm reading comma separated values from a file. I use a remove function to remove the comma. Where I'm having problems is iterating through the string. I feel like the `for` loop I'm using to iterate through the string is correct, but I'm probably doing something really stupid because the program fails miserably. So, how do I correctly iterate through a string?

each line in the file has a format similar to:

```
0000000000001110,1
```

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void removeChar(char *str, char garbage);

int main(){
    FILE *ifp;
    char *mode = "r";
    ifp = fopen("in.csv", mode);


    char* string;

    int i, len;
    while(fscanf(ifp, "%s", string)!=EOF){
        removeChar(string, ',');
        printf("%s \n", string); //gives me correct output of string with no comma
        len = strlen(string);
        for(i=0; i<len; i++)        //where the error occurs
            printf("%c", string[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}

void removeChar(char *str, char garbage) {

    char *src, *dst;
    for (src = dst = str; *src != '\0'; src++) {
        *dst = *src;
        if (*dst != garbage) dst++;
    }
    *dst = '\0';
}
```

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: @haris There actually is no error, the program just crashes.

Comment: I've been able to iterate through a string using the same method but in a different program. I don't know what's different here that's causing an error.

Comment: You need to allocate memory for your `string` with `malloc()`.  Otherwise, it is just a pointer that points to random location.

Comment: Replace `char* string;`  by `char string[MAXLEN];` where MAXLEN is the maximum length of your lines in in.csv.

Comment: @SSC I can't believe that's all it was.. wow I suck at C. Thank you.

Comment: @Ybarra If you decided to use `malloc()`, please remember to call `free()` after you are done using it.  Or you can follow Michanel Walz's suggestion to use array instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have defined `string` as:

```
char* string;
```

but you have not allocated memory for it before using it to read data from the file. This leads to undefined behavior.

Suggestion:

1. Use an array.
2. Use `fgets` instead of `fscanf`. `fgets` is safer than `fscanf` since you are specifying the maximum number of characters to read.

Here's an updated version of `main`.

```
int main(){
    FILE *ifp;
    char *mode = "r";
    ifp = fopen("in.csv", mode);

    // Use an array of char.
    char string[1024];

    int i, len;
    // Use fgets instead of fscanf.
    while(fgets(string, 1024, ifp) != NULL) {
        removeChar(string, ',');
        printf("%s \n", string); //gives me correct output of string with no comma
        len = strlen(string);
        for(i=0; i<len; i++)        //where the error occurs
            printf("%c", string[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Provide valid memory to the pointer `char* string;` before proceeding the fscanf.

Else, try like this

`char string[1000];` //Here string is character array.

Answer (score 1):

Pasting another solution. It filters input chars what is pretty fast when reading a big CSV file.

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define LINE_MAXLEN     (1024)

static size_t
readline(char *buff, FILE *fp)
{
        register char c;
        char *p = buff;
        while ((c = fgetc(fp)) > 43) if (c > 47) *p++ = c; // ord(',') == 44 and ord('0') == 48
        *p = 0;
        return (p - buff);
}

int
main(void)
{
        char line[LINE_MAXLEN];
        FILE *fp;

        if ((fp = fopen("in.csv", "r")) == NULL)
                perror("Error opening file");

        while (readline(line, fp))
                printf("line=%s\n", line);

        return (0);
}
```